# USB mic input + 3.5mm jack output

Tags: audio, pi-3b+, alsa, microphone

I'm trying to set up my Rpi using a USB mic and output through the 3.5mm jack.

If I select the USB mic in `alsamixer`, I don't have any sound at all. If I use the 3.5mm I get sound but cannot record with the mic.

See also: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=248764

Comment: kan skriva på mitt modersmål om du tycker det är lättare? Då jag måste skriva på ett språk jag inte använder. *[can write in my native language if you think it's easier? Then I have to write in a language I do not use.]*

Comment: For better or worse we are English only.  Use google translate (it detected your Swedish and translated it clearly and, I think, accurately).  Then just include a note that you used google translate in case anything comes out funny.

Comment: Some stuff in the translation did come out a bit funny, so I've taken your original edit and cleaned it up to match what I think you mean.  Unfortunately I can't help with the problem, other than to say I think you might need to work with *pulseaudio* to mix input/output sources.

Comment: @not2qubit  dont know if this work, but maybe you can help me?